# MYSQL All records from one table and only the last joined record from other table

Tags: mysql, join

I have the next two tables

Tabel Name

```
id -  Name   
1  -  Jack   
2  -  Roger   
3  -  Peter    
4  -  Clark  
5  -  Gerard
```

and

Table numbers

```
id  - name_id  -  number
1  -       1 -          10
2  -       1 -          20
3  -       2 -          30
4  -       2 -          40
5  -       3 -          50
6  -       3 -          60
7  -       4 -          70
8  -       4 -          80
9  -       5 -          90
10 -       5 -         100
```

Now in need the next outcome of a mysql query

```
name.id - name.name - numbers.id – numbers.number
  1     -   Jack    -      2     -       20 
  2     -   Roger   -      4     -       40
  3     -   Peter   -      6     -       60
  4     -   Clark   -      8     -       80
  5     -   Gerard  -      10    -      100
```

In short.
All the records of the name table and only the last join from the number table.

thnx

Comment: This question is asked every. single. day. here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a field where save the date, ill assume the last inserted item will have the higher id value.

Check this out: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bf2e1/7)